# Projective variety minus hyperplane $=$ affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

**Claim:** Let $V \subset \mathbb{C}P^n$ be a non-singular projective algebraic variety of complex dimension $k$ and let $P \subset \mathbb{C}P^n$ be a hyperplane.
Then $V \setminus (V \cap P)$ is a complex $k$-dimensional non-singular affine algebraic variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

This fact is used (but not proved) in J. Milnors book *Morse Theory* in the proof of the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem (Corollary 7.3). 
(Actually, there it would be enough to know that $V \setminus (V \cap P)$ is a complex manifold of dimension $k$, but still the above is stated.)

**My thoughts so far:**

I first proved that $\mathbb{C}P^n \setminus P \cong \mathbb{C}^n$. 
Therefore the embedding in $\mathbb{C}^n$ doesn't cause any problem.

Now assume that $p_1, \ldots, p_j : \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are complex homogeneous polynomials such that the variety $V$ is induced from the set 
$$\bigcap_{r=1}^j p_r^{-1}(0) \subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}.$$
Furthermore let $l: \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a linear polynomial such that $P = l^{-1}(0)$. 
Then I would like to write something like
\begin{align}
V \setminus (V \cap P) &= V \cap (V \cap P)^c = V \cap P^c \\
&= \left( \bigcap p_r^{-1}(0) \right) \cap \{ l \neq 0 \} \\
&\overset{?}{=} \bigcap \left( \frac{p_r}{l} \right)^{-1}(0)
\end{align}
where the $p_r$ now denote the induced functions $\mathbb{C}P^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$.
Then $V \setminus (V \cap P)$ would be cut out by the "polynomials" $\frac{p_r}{l}$ and I'd be done. But this doesn't seem to be formally correct...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is almost correct. But instead of $\frac{p_r}{l}$ you need $\frac{p_r}{\lambda_r}$, where $\lambda_r$ is $l$ raised to the power $\operatorname{deg }p_r$. These $p_r/\lambda_r$ give actual polynomials on $\mathbf C^n$, cutting out your affine variety.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why are te $p_r/\lambda_r$ actual polynomials? And why in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and not in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$? For example in the case $n=1$ consider $p, l: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $p(z_1, z_2) = z_1 z_2$ and $l(z_1, z_2) = z_1 + z_2$. Then $\frac{p}{l^2} = \frac{z_1 z_2}{z_1^2 + 2z_1 z_2 + z_2^2}$ is not a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$ right?

Comment: They are homogeneous rational functions of degree 0 on C^{n+1} with poles only along $l^{-1}(0)$. So they descend to well-defined functions on $P^n \setminus P \sim C^n$.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. Now I only still need to show the non-singularity of $V \setminus (V \cap P)$. It would make sense, if this simply follows from the non-singularity of $V$, since $V \setminus (V \cap P)$ is a subset of $V$. However I only really know the definition of non-singularity as the requirement that the derivative of the combined function $\bigoplus_{r=1}^j p_r$ is surjective at every point in the variety. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know what the "combined function" you refer to is. Are you talking about the Jacobian criterion?

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad terminology. Yes, I believe I'm just talking about the Jacobian Criterion. So in our case we'd have to show that the derivative of $\bigoplus_{r=1}^j \frac{p_r}{\lambda_r}$ is surjective at every point in $V \setminus (V \cap P)$. I also just noticed that in general a subset of a non-singular algebraic variety which is itself a variety need not necessarily be non-singular. So the above argument wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Dear Tom,for an _open_ subset of a non-singular variety, this is true.I don't have time to write out the details now, but you can try to work through the definitions yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algebraic projective variety $V\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is given by the zero locus of homogeneous polynomials $f_i\in \mathbb{C}[x_0,\dots,x_n]$.

Take now the open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ where $x_0\not=0$, which is an affine space. You can assume that $x_0=1$ and obtain then coordinates $x_1,\dots,x_n$. This gives an isomorphism
$$\begin{array}{rcl}\mathbb{C}^n&\to& U\\
(x_1,\dots,x_n)&\mapsto & [1:x_1:\dots:x_n]\end{array}$$

Then $U\cap V$ is the locus of points of the form $[x_0:\dots:x_n]$ such that $x_0=1$ and $f_i(x_0,\dots,x_n)=0$. This shows that you obtain an affine variety given by the polynomials $f_i(1,x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

This process is very classical and can be founded in any course of algebraic geometry.